# EOFError: end of file reached error and then memory error on heroku with workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a worker on heroku (1x) that I use for a sidekiq background process. This process basically cycles through all users and sends them an sms message via twilio.

Everything worked fine for months now but the last two times my customer tried to use this feature, it failed. I'm not sure why it failed the first time, but the most recent time (today), the worker failed and said:

```
EOFError: end of file reached
```

then, when looking at heroku logs --tail, it kept saying this over and over again:

```
2014-07-18T01:06:59.544697+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process running mem=804M(157.2%)
2014-07-18T01:06:59.544945+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

restarting the server finally fixed it. I had this exact issue a while ago that I thought I fixed. Here's my sidekiq.rb file:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  pool_size = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = pool_size
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

why is this happening all of a sudden? their user base is growing for sure, but it's not THAT much more than when it was working all the other times. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As answered in your other question you can use find_each to make sure not that many are loaded and feed that data into librato to monitor